# Drop file into app and copy that file to a folder

Tags: node.js, nwjs

**NOTE**: I know about the [Filereader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) however I don't want to read the file unless it's clicked on the app. Let me explain.

My project tree files are located at `__dirname + "/content/project"`

I'm working on an IDE and I'd like to be able to drag and drop a file (or files) into the file tree. (can be any file type .dll, .sh etc:)

**Screenshot**
[image]

So say I was dragging `application.exe` from my Desktop and dropped it into my file tree.

I'd like to be able to essentially copy that file from my desktop and paste it into `__dirname + "/content/project"`.

I don't know if this is even possible.

Put another way, how can I copy one file from one location, to another location via drag and drop; without reading the files contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent many many hours the past few days looking into this and it looks as if it's not possible (at least currently).

My best option is to use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). So when a text file is dropped, detect it's file type and if the app supports it say a text file I can save the file with the same name and type in the folder; If it's an image I can convert it to a dataurl/base64.

Kind of sucks but best I can do for now.